# Dispatch an action after receiving a message from firebase cloud messaging

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

There is any way to dispatch an action from redux store in react.js app after receiving a message from firebase cloud messaging?
I tried to dispatch my action in getToken() function after checking the validity of the token, but what happened is the action kept dispatching all the time and performed hundreds of requests in the network. (the token is valid and connected)
I tried also to dispatch the action in onMessage function, but the action didn't dispatched!